# Button enbale/disable (inside Datagrid view ) based on value from Database -WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, data-binding, datagrid

In WPF window, Data grid view will load from database.

This is the design code for Data grid view.(It contains 2 columns - Name, Action)

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"  Binding="{Binding Name}"  Width="160"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button Name="btnEdit" Content="Edit" />
                            <Button Name="btnDelete" Content="Delete" />
                            <Button Name="btnActivate" Content="Activate" />
                            <Button Name="btnDeactivate" Content="Deactivate" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Name column bind the value from data base value, and following column contain 4 buttons!
[image]

what I need to do this, based on another column value of database (for example Activation Status) , the btnActivate, btnDeactivate should set their
is Enable property!
how can I accomplish this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initiate binding to appropriate property from your button:

```
 <Button Name="btnEdit"
            Content="Edit"
            IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.ActivationStatus, Converter={StaticResource MyStatusToBooleanConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should (providing your value in the DB is a boolean), use bindings to set the states.

For example:

```
<Button Name="btnActivate" Content="Activate" IsEnabled="{Binding ClassPropertyType}" />
```

And then when you set your ItemSource with a list of your class, it will bind to the set boolean.